# Splitting content from a single folder to multiple sub folders using Python

Tags: python, directory

In my file, I have a large number of images in **jpg** format and they are named **[fruit type].[index].jpg**.
Instead of manually making three new sub folders to copy and paste the images into each sub folder, is there some python code that can parse through the name of the images and choose where to redirect the image to based on the `fruit type` in the name, at the same time create a new sub folder when a new `fruit type` is parsed?

---

**Before**

- TrainingSet (file)

  - apple.100.jpg
  - apple.101.jpg
  - apple.102.jpg
  - apple.103.jpg
  - peach.100.jpg
  - peach.101.jpg
  - peach.102.jpg
  - orange.100.jpg
  - orange.101.jpg

---

**After**

- TrainingSet (file)

  - apple(file)

    - apple.100.jpg
    - apple.101.jpg
    - apple.102.jpg
    - apple.103.jpg
  - peach(file)

    - peach.100.jpg
    - peach.101.jpg
    - peach.102.jpg
  - orange(file)

    - orange.100.jpg
    - orange.101.jpg

Comment: Plz accept my answer as accepted/correct, as it works for every one. Thank u.

Answer (score 10):

Here’s the code to do just that, if you need help merging this into your codebase let me know:

```
import os, os.path, shutil

folder_path = "test"

images = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]

for image in images:
    folder_name = image.split('.')[0]

    new_path = os.path.join(folder_path, folder_name)
    if not os.path.exists(new_path):
        os.makedirs(new_path)

    old_image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, image)
    new_image_path = os.path.join(new_path, image)
    shutil.move(old_image_path, new_image_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are all formatted similarly to the three fruit example you gave, you can simply do a string.split(".")[0] on each filename you encounter:

```
import os

for image in images:
    fruit = image.split(".")[0]
    if not os.path.isdir(fruit):
        os.mkdir(fruit)
    os.rename(os.path.join(fruit, image))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, hope it helps

```
   import os
   from pathlib import Path
   import shutil

   folder_path = "images/"
   nameList=[]
   for image in os.listdir(folder_paths):
     folder_name = image.split('.')[0]
     nameList.append(folder_name)
    
   for f in os.listdir(folder_paths):
     Path(folder_name).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True,mode=0o755)
     des = folder_name +"/"+str(f)
     old_path = folder_paths+str(f)
     for path in nameList:
        if f.endswith('.jpg'):
                print(f)
                if path == folder_name:
                  shutil.move(old_path, str(des))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).